# Post-Build script throws error in VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, project

I've seen several threads with the same issue, but none of the solutions seems to work for me so I'm trying it here.

I need a post-build script in VS2010 that moves a .lib file to a directroy (which possibly dosn't exist yet; if so create it).

I am using this, which returns `error code 2`:

```
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName).lib"
```

Also tried, which returns `error code 1`: (what is the difference?)

```
copy /y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName).lib"
```

The most common issues people seem to hav is the lack of quotes on paths, but I have that.

Why dosn't it work?

Comment: Error code 2 means that the user canceled the xcopy operation. You probably need to specify the `/q` switch.

Comment: you mean adding /q after /y? did not make a difference when I tried

Comment: Do your environment or project variables have appropriate slashes? Consider echoing your source and target to the console or a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to be closer:

```
if not exist "$(SolutionDir)lib" md "$(SolutionDir)lib"
xcopy /y /d "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)lib"
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick test on the command line what's happening with `copy` is it is failing because the directory does not exist. What is happening with `xcopy` is it is failing when it prompts for whether the target is a file or directory when it finds the directory doesn't exist. `/-Y` may be set in your COPYCMD environment variable or your target path may be misleading causing a prompt for whether the target is a directory or file which is not supressed by the `/Y` flag for overwrite.

Example: `xcopy /Y "C:\test.txt" "missingdirectory\test5.txt"`

Obviously the easiest solution is to check if the directory exists and create it if it's missing before doing the copy in your post-build script.